# JUnit testing with spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to create a junit test for a spring controller method but I keep receiving the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, 
or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, 
your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:123)
```

I have added both the things it tells me I need (I've tried each one separately) and currently my  web.xml contains

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

<filter> 
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 
    <filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

and the method I'm trying to test is something along the lines of

```
@Controller
@RemotingDestination
public class MyController {

public Response foo()
    {
//...
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession httpSession = attr.getRequest().getSession(true);
//...
}
```

and my junit test simply calls myController.foo() and checks the reponse.  So I can't create a mock object to pass into the method to get around this issue.

So I suppose my question is, does there exist some configuration or trick that I have yet to stumble upon that will make this run without having to refactor my controller method?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear. Unfortunately your code requires a bit of a rewrite.

First of all while testing your controller you (obviously) are not inside a web request. That's why `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` does not work. But you can make your test to pass *and* refactor the code to be much more readable using the following technique (assuming you need an HTTP session to get some actual attribute from it):

```
public Response foo(@SessionAttribute("someSessionAttribute") int id)
```

This way Spring MVC will automatically fetch the session and load `someSessionAttribute` when inside a web request (and even perform required conversion). But when you are testing the controller, just call the method with fixed parameter. No request/session infrastructure code. Much cleaner (note that the two lines in `foo` you've provided aren't needed at all).

The other solution is to register `RequestScope` manually. See example [here](http://www.javathinking.com/2009/06/no-scope-registered-for-scope-request/). This should work without modifying any of your code with mocked request and session.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!  To help clarify what I did to solve my problem for anyone who reads this in the future -- I used `@SessionAttributes("mySessionAttribute") public class AccountController { ...}` and my method ended up looking like `public Response foo(@ModelAttribute("mySessionAttribute") Object myObject) {...}` 

Whether or not this will work for my situation in the long term remains to be seen, but for now this works.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: In case someone stumbles upon this, I have found a solution that requires no refactoring.  Do everything mentioned in pbdavey's post at [link](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-50722.html).